# Set-Content using variables

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to generate PowerShell scripts using a PowerShell script.  How do I get the variables' values inside the content of the newly generated script?

```cs
foreach ($server in $testServers) {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Name "$($server)_wu.ps1" -Path "D:\tools\windows updates\uscripts"

    Set-Content -Path "D:\tools\windows updates\uscripts\$($server)_wu.ps1" -Value {
        $computer = $server

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
            Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
            Find-Module PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module -Force | Import-Module -Force
        }

        $updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count

        while ($updatesCount -gt "0") {
            psexec \\$computer -s "powershell.exe "Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm:`$false -IgnoreReboot""
            Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force -Wait
            $updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count
        }
    }
}
```

The result here is the following:

```cs
$computer = $server

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
    Find-Module PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module -Force | Import-Module -Force
}

$updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count

while ($updatesCount -gt "0") {
    psexec \\$computer -s "powershell.exe "Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm:`$false -IgnoreReboot""
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force -Wait
    $updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count
}
```

But, in the new script, I'd like to have `$server` replaced by the name of the server for which the script is generated.

Comment: The obvious solution is to make your "value" a string variable where you can do whatever changes you need before setting the content.

Comment: I've tried to put the new script inside a `$value` variable.  `$value` is a string.  I `Set-Content` using this `$value`... but I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do what you're asking is probably to use a [here-string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) and insert particular values via the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx) (`-f`):

```
foreach ($server in $testServers) {
    @'
$computer = '{0}'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
    Find-Module PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module -Force | Import-Module -Force
}

$updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count

while ($updatesCount -gt "0") {
    psexec \\$computer -s 'powershell.exe "Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm:$false -IgnoreReboot"'
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force -Wait
    $updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $computer).Count
}
'@ -f $server | Set-Content -Path "D:\tools\windows updates\uscripts\${server}_wu.ps1"
}
```

However, I'd argue that writing one parameterized script and invoking that with the respective computer name might be a more appropriate solution than creating one script per computer:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Computer
)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
    Find-Module PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module -Force | Import-Module -Force
}

$updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $Computer).Count

while ($updatesCount -gt "0") {
    psexec \\$Computer -s 'powershell.exe "Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm:$false -IgnoreReboot"'
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Computer -Force -Wait
    $updatesCount = (Get-WindowsUpdate -ComputerName $Computer).Count
}
```

Invocation:

```
PS> script.ps1 -Computer FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright - so I couldn't figure out how to manipulate my string and ended up solving it like this...  Any shorter, simpler answer is absolutely welcome (note that the rest of the script changed a bit as well)

```
foreach ($server in $testServers) {

    New-Item -ItemType File -Name "$($server)_wu.ps1" -Path "\\VILV12ICTSCRIPT\d$\windowsupdates\uscripts"

    $value = '

    $computer = $PSCommandPath
    $computer = $computer.Split("`\")[3]
    $computer = $computer.Split("_")[0]

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {

        Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
        Find-Module PSWindowsUpdate | Install-Module -Force | Import-Module -Force

    }

    $updatesCount = (PsExec.exe \\$computer -s "powershell.exe "Get-WindowsUpdate"").Count

    while ($updatesCount -gt "0") {

        psexec \\$computer -s "powershell.exe "Install-WindowsUpdate -Confirm:`$false -IgnoreReboot""
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Force -Wait
        $updatesCount = (PsExec.exe \\$computer -s "powershell.exe "Get-WindowsUpdate"").Count

    }

    Write-Host "No more updates available for $($computer)" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

    '

    Set-Content -Path "\\VILV12ICTSCRIPT\d$\windowsupdates\uscripts\$($server)_wu.ps1" -Value $value

}
```

And both the script to generate and the generated scripts work like charms (^^,)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just used a tick mark to escape the dollar symbol. When it writes to file it writes it without the tick mark.